# What are the decomposition based forecasting methods?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references, decomposition

I would like to learn that all forecasting methods are doing decomposition initially. For example, as I know, MAPA method is decomposing the time-series data first, then apply forecasting. If not all models perform decomposition, could you please tell me which methods are decomposing the signal first then forecast?